# How to draw the graph in android based on its height and size

Tags: android

i want to draw a graph in a area and i used a linear layout as area.i want to set the size of the graph area,which should be compatible to small,medium ,default emulators etc.i need to set the size for graph  area,how can i do it in xml file

for eg in blackberry we use Display.getWidth();Similar is there way to get the width of the display either programmatically or in xml

To expand my area, i did like this, in below image (just added label,which gets an height)

[image](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b0da255/n/testAndroid1.JPG)

To expand it ,i added somemore like this

[image1](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b0da256/n/testAndroid2.JPG)

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.p

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the width from the xml. You can get it programmatically from your View:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {

}
```

onSizeChanged is called whenever the size of the View changes (including the time the View is first constructed). Alternatively you can use getWidth() inside onDraw:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  int width = this.getWidth();
}
```

Comment: is there any way giving width values to the layout,so that it can redraw itself,i just added two links to the post,u just chk that and tell me,what can be donr